# Interchange variables in LaTeX (to be used with TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I want to define a couple of variables in LaTeX and then exchange their values, like this (but it doesn't work):

```
\newcommand{\signS}{$+$}
\newcommand{\signT}{$-$}
\newcommand{\signU}{}
\signS
\renewcommand{\signU}{\signS}
\renewcommand{\signS}{\signT}
\renewcommand{\signT}{\signU}
\signS
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

As suggested in the answers below, using `\let` solves the problem. However, I want to use this inside a `\foreach` loop in TikZ, where it doesn't seem to work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1, 2, 3, 4} {
        \signS
        \let\signU\signS
        \let\signS\signT
        \let\signT\signU
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Prefix the `\let`s with `\global`.  The `\foreach` stuff takes place inside a group so the assignments are local and reset each time through the loop.

Comment: `\global` does the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `\let` instead of `\renewcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\newcommand{\signS}{$+$}%
\newcommand{\signT}{$-$}%
\newcommand{\signU}{}%
%
\begin{document}
    old \textbackslash signS: \signS

    \let\signU\signS
    \let\signS\signT
    \let\signT\signU
    new \textbackslash signS: \signS
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is probably to replace `\renewcommand{\signU}{\signS}` by `\let\signU\signS`, etc. Then `\signU` is assigned the current meaning of `\signS`.

Your method does not work because `\renewcommand` does not expand the definition text at the time of definition. Instead, it is expanded when the command is used.